# How to print char array from index n in Arduino

Tags: c++, arrays, c, arduino

Let's imagine I have

```
String x = "hello there";
```

So I can print it from index e.g. 1 as:

```
Serial.println(x.substring(1));
```

> ello there

I wanna do the same with

```
char x[] = "hello there";
```

Any ideas? **(Except using loops to print char by char)**

Comment: `Serial.println(x + 1);` `x + 1` here adds one byte to a pointer to memory location x

Comment: @Lundin Ha Ha!:) I knew strings are char arrays but never thought about passing a pointer to the print function.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the & operator to get the string after the desired index like this:

```
Serial.println(&x[1]);
```